# If then statement change existing column

Tags: if-statement, teradata

How can I do this. I tried a case statement but have issues getting it to work

```
if Tax_or_Flat = 'tax' then flat = 0
```

`Tax_or_Flat` is a column title
`flata` is a column title

maybe

```
,CASE WHEN Tax_or_Flat = 'tax' THEN Flata = 0 ELSE Tax_or_Flat END
```

but thats not working

```
select 
a.time_amt as Amt_Day
,a.rate_mix as AVG_Day_Rate
,a.psbdats as Poss_Days_Bil_Ins
,a.acct as Bill_to_Amount
,a.LGCY_AUTH_AMT_TXT as Auth_Amt
      ,case when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%TAX%'  then 'tax'
       when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%DAY%'  then 'flat'
            else 0
            end as Tax_or_Flat
     ,((Amt_Day - AVG_Day_Rate ) * Poss_Days_Bil_Ins) as Tax
       ,((Amt_Day * Poss_Days_Bil_Ins) - Bill_to_Amount) aS Flat


from JTable.Loan a

where a.rate_mix = 5
```

Comment: Not used Teradata, but hazarding a guess that you cannot assign in the CASE.  So in the first THEN you have Flat = 0 ELSE ....  I'd remove the Flat = and just have THEN 0.

Comment: Is `flata` an already existing column, or one you want to create with this query?

Comment: But wouldnt that change the Tax_or_Flat column? What I am trying to do (not necessarily with a case statement) is if column Tax_or_flat = 'tax' then clange the current value in column named Flat to zero.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It already is there, Im trying to change an existing not create a new.

Comment: It sounds like you want to do an `UPDATE`

Comment: Sorry, kind of new, how would that look

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table_name
SET flata = CASE WHEN Tax_or_Flat = 'tax' THEN 0 ELSE Tax_or_Flat END
```

This will change the value of `flata` to `0` when Tax_or_Flat = 'tax', and it will give it the value in the Tax_or_Flat column in all other cases.

Check the syntax for Teradata, but this is the basic idea of what you are attempting.

** EDIT **

If this is just a `SELECT` that you are trying to perform, and not change any actual table data, you can either do a nested subquery:

```
select *,case when Tax_or_Flat = 'tax' THEN 0 ELSE Tax_or_Flat END as flata
from (
select 
a.time_amt as Amt_Day
,a.rate_mix as AVG_Day_Rate
,a.psbdats as Poss_Days_Bil_Ins
,a.acct as Bill_to_Amount
,a.LGCY_AUTH_AMT_TXT as Auth_Amt
      ,case when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%TAX%'  then 'tax'
       when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%DAY%'  then 'flat'
            else 0
            end as Tax_or_Flat
     ,((Amt_Day - AVG_Day_Rate ) * Poss_Days_Bil_Ins) as Tax
       ,((Amt_Day * Poss_Days_Bil_Ins) - Bill_to_Amount) aS Flat


from JTable.Loan a

where a.rate_mix = 5
) a
```

or rewrite the logic within the query:

```
select 
a.time_amt as Amt_Day
,a.rate_mix as AVG_Day_Rate
,a.psbdats as Poss_Days_Bil_Ins
,a.acct as Bill_to_Amount
,a.LGCY_AUTH_AMT_TXT as Auth_Amt
,case when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%TAX%'  then 'tax'
      when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%DAY%'  then 'flat'
      else 0
end as Tax_or_Flat
,((Amt_Day - AVG_Day_Rate ) * Poss_Days_Bil_Ins) as Tax
,((Amt_Day * Poss_Days_Bil_Ins) - Bill_to_Amount) aS Flat
,case when (case when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%TAX%'  then 'tax'
            when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%DAY%'  then 'flat'
            else 0 end) = 'tax' 
      then 0 
      else (case when Auth_Amt LIKE 'TAX%'
                 then 'tax'
                when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%DAY%'     
                then 'flat'
                else 0
            end)
  end AS flata

from JTable.Loan a

where a.rate_mix = 5
```

Comment: Thanks, so I have to do it on a save table or can I add it to the code existing? Like right before the where statement

Comment: This statement on its own will work. If you are trying to make it part of a larger code, you may have to post a bit more of your code in your question to get an accurate answer

Comment: Thank you for your help. So much. I updated the code to show the whole thing. I am trying to add it after the Flat and Tax columns as established

Answer (score 0):

Based on your SELECT you seems to want something like this:

```
select 
a.time_amt as Amt_Day
,a.rate_mix as AVG_Day_Rate
,a.psbdats as Poss_Days_Bil_Ins
,a.acct as Bill_to_Amount
,a.LGCY_AUTH_AMT_TXT as Auth_Amt
  ,case when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%TAX%'  then 'tax'
   when Auth_Amt  LIKE '%DAY%'  then 'flat'
        else '0'
        end as Tax_or_Flat
  ,case when Tax_or_Flat = 'tax' 
        then ((Amt_Day - AVG_Day_Rate ) * Poss_Days_Bil_Ins) 
        else 0 
   end as Tax
  ,case when Tax_or_Flat = 'flat' 
        THEN ((Amt_Day * Poss_Days_Bil_Ins) - Bill_to_Amount) 
        else 0 
   end AS Flat    

from JTable.Loan a

where a.rate_mix = 5
```

Comment: This creates a new column correct? I am trying to update and existing ciolumn

Comment: @Matt: You need to be more specific what you actually want, your description plus query is bit confusing. There's no column named `flata` in your SELECT, did you mean `flat` instead?